# AWS iOS SDK 1.7.1 Network Connection Lost

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, grand-central-dispatch

I have some code that has been in production for a while now and all of a sudden doesn't work at all.  I am getting an error that looks like:

```
[S3Response connection:didFailWithError:]|234|UserInfo.NSUnderlyingError = Error      Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x15514d30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://our-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/t46945%2Fx0f04n77vo3724ky_3000.mp4}
```

There is also an issue where the SDK calls both the `request:didFailWithError:` and `request:didCompleteWithResponse:` are both called for a single request.  I was doing some digging and saw there is a [similar issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/52) for `GetObject`.

We are getting a crash because when we start a request we enter a dispatch group and leave it on the completion or failure of the request but when both all called it throws an exception and crashes the app.

Any help as to why this is happening would be great.

Comment: Is your bucket located in a different region than US Standard? You may want to explicitly set the endpoint of your S3 client to reflect this.

Comment: No it is in US Standard, and we have used this setup for years.

Answer (score 0):

After running the network connections through my computer and using **Charles** to inspect the traffic it turns out that **Amazon** was returning an error for `RequestTimeTooSkewed` but it doesn't make it to the error. The devices had their times manually adjusted. I now have a server side api endpoint to get the current *server* time and calculate the device difference. You can then set the `runtimeClockSkew` by calling `[AmazonSDKUtil setRuntimeClockSkew:difference];`